# VBA Json Parse- Parser is not breaking down the Json Correctly

Tags: json, vba, parsing

I have been trying to parse a bit of JSON data from an API as part of a larger project and due to my limited experience with VBA/Json I am having difficulties figuring out what the problem is with my VBA code.

I have used the following VBA Json Parsers and all basically stop working at the same point and give me an "incomplete parse".
vba-json https://code.google.com/archive/p/vba-json
vbjson www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680

The Json I am trying to parse is the following:

```
{"links":[],"content":{"carrier":{"allowedToOperate":"Y","bipdInsuranceOnFile":"1000","bipdInsuranceRequired":"Y","bipdRequiredAmount":"750","bondInsuranceOnFile":"0","bondInsuranceRequired":"N","brokerAuthorityStatus":"N","cargoInsuranceOnFile":"0","cargoInsuranceRequired":"N","carrierOperation":{"carrierOperationCode":"A","carrierOperationDesc":"Interstate"},"commonAuthorityStatus":"A","contractAuthorityStatus":"A","crashTotal":19,"dbaName":null,"dotNumber":124871,"driverInsp":974,"driverOosInsp":33,"driverOosRate":3.38809034907597535934291581108829568789,"driverOosRateNationalAverage":"5.51","ein":460396676,"fatalCrash":0,"hazmatInsp":0,"hazmatOosInsp":0,"hazmatOosRate":0,"hazmatOosRateNationalAverage":"4.5","injCrash":6,"isPassengerCarrier":"N","issScore":null,"legalName":"A&A EXPRESS LLC","oosDate":null,"oosRateNationalAverageYear":"2009-2010","phone":"6055822402","phyCity":"BRANDON","phyCountry":"US","phyState":"SD","phyStreet":"1015 9TH AVENUE NORTH","phyZipcode":"57005","reviewDate":"2016-09-23","reviewType":"N","safetyRating":"S","safetyRatingDate":"2008-08-29","safetyReviewDate":"2016-09-23","safetyReviewType":"N","snapshotDate":"1485493200000","statusCode":"A","totalDrivers":237,"totalPowerUnits":253,"towawayCrash":13,"vehicleInsp":477,"vehicleOosInsp":58,"vehicleOosRate":12.15932914046121593291404612159329140461,"vehicleOosRateNationalAverage":"20.72"},"links"
```

my VBA code looks like the following:

```
Public Sub PARSEJSON()
Dim reader As New XMLHTTP60
Dim api As Object
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim item As Variant

reader.Open "GET", "https://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/qc/services/carriers/124871?webKey=APIKEY", False
reader.send

    Set WS = ActiveSheet
    Set api = JSON.parse(reader.responseText)
        For Each item In api
            WS.Range("a3").Value = item("")


        Next


End Sub
```

I cannot get into the JSON to reference the values that I need because the parser yields a result like:

[photo of watcher in VBA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGAIp.png)

it seems like the Json parser is only breaking down part of the Json string from the API, it is from a government website so I am assuming it should be in a common Json format. I hope I included enough detail in this post to encompass the scope of my issue

Comment: Please check that your JSON string is valid.

Comment: I checked the string at https://jsonlint.com/ and it says its valid Json! @Cubi

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue, I looked further into how to reference a dictionary and realized I was using the wrong syntax to reference and adding in extra steps that were not needed.

new VBA code yields the results I want:

```
Public Sub PARSEJSON()
Dim reader As New XMLHTTP60
Dim dict As Object
Dim api As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim json As New Class1
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim key As Variant
Dim item As Variant



reader.Open "GET", "https://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/qc/services/carriers/124871?webKey=APIKEY", False
reader.send

    Set WS = ActiveSheet
    Set api = json.parse(reader.responseText)
        MsgBox api("content")("carrier").Count
        MsgBox api.item("content")("carrier")("driverOosInsp")
        WS.Range("a1").value = api.item("content")("carrier")("driverOosInsp")
End Sub
```